# Can a decider return "Undecidable" on the Halting Problem?

Tags: turing-machines, computability, halting-problem

So, I know there is no general algorithm for the halting problem, but I was curious if a three output decider could at least give us "an" output **{0 if doesn't halt, 1 if halts, U if undecidable for this decider}**.

Here's the halting problem, roughly, in python:

```
    # The decider function tries to determine if a function 'f' halts or not
def decider(f, x):
    try:
        return f(x)
#This is just a stand in for the logic which works fine for our example
    except RecursionError:
        return "doesn't halt"

# Function 'g' is an "adversarial" function
def g(y):
    # If decider says it halts, go into an infinite loop
    if decider(g, y) == "halt":
        while True:
            pass
    # If decider says it doesn't halt, then halt
    elif decider(g, y) == "doesn't halt":
        return "halt"

# Test the decider on the adversarial function 'g'
# This will lead to an infinite loop or a recursion error, depending on the Python interpreter.
result = decider(g, "some_input")
print(result)
```

Here's the same with the logic for returning in cases which we are not able to solve:

```
# Function to check if a function is "adversarial"
def is_adversarial(f):
#this is where the logic would go, for our case, we just single out g()
    return f == g

# The decider function with added adversarial checking
def decider(f, x):
    if is_adversarial(f):
        return "Unable to determine for this problem set."
    try:
        return f(x)
    except RecursionError:
        return "doesn't halt"

# Function 'g' is an "adversarial" function
def g(y):
    if decider(g, y) == "halt":
        while True:
            pass
    elif decider(g, y) == "doesn't halt":
        return "halt"

# Test the decider on the adversarial function 'g'
# This should return "Unable to determine for this problem set."
result = decider(g, "some_input")
print(result)
```

Note that even if we tried to leverage the "is_adversarial" result, any decision it makes will be countermanded by g() due to the fact that g() explicitly calls decider() and countermands it. It is equivalent to receiving the news that you will die tomorrow and saying "ah, but if you got that information, you would be able to avoid death," but in fact, it is something entirely outside of your control, assuming you are deterministically defined. I want to make this explicit as I think it trips a lot of people up in my explanation, and their assumption the above would reduce to the halting problem.

It may not seem useful, but if there is nothing that demonstrates it to be contradictory, I can use it in another thing I'm working on that is useful.

Comment: Be aware that your explanations are particularly obscure.

Comment: @YvesDaoust agreed, I have changed most of it to code to make it easier to orient within the problem.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/162015/755, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4768396/14578.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Comment: Please ask only one question per post.  It's not clear what you are asking.  I see two different questions in this post: "Can a decider return "Undecidable" on the Halting Problem?" and "Does there exist a partition A⊔B...?"  Those are not the same question.  Please determine which question you want answered, and [edit] your question to ask that one question.  If you have multiple questions, you can ask each separately in its own post.

Comment: Good point, removing the other question.

Comment: There is no question in the body of your post. What is the actual question you want answered? The flurry of edits does not really help either...

Comment: I am confused. You `decider` doesn't decide anything; it just runs a function on an argument. A `decider` would take `f` as the only argument and return `True` or `False`. Also, there is no such thing as a `RecursionError` in Turing Machines.

Comment: Right, this seems like a semantic distinction

Comment: It is pretty clear though what I'm asking. I just wasn't sure if there was a different term. Regardless it returns for all outputs, it just doesn't offer a productive answer for the halting problem on all outputs. As for recursion error, again, this seems pedantic, I obviously am not going to create a full algorithmic representation which "solves" the halting problem, I can't nor can anyone, it's just meant to represent the solver.

Comment: A decider is only allowed to answer a (yes or no) question, thus not allowed to say neither. A decidability decider can answer (yes or no) for whether or not a finite string is decidable for a certain criteria.

Answer (score 4):

Presumably, you don't use the term "undecidable" in its formal sense. It is easy to write a program that returns "halts", "does not halt" or "don't know". In particular, a program that always returns "don't know" can do (though there are also less trivial solutions, for instance by detecting Pascal-style for and while loops).

I don't see in what way this would "break" the Halting problem.

Comment: It would not break the halting problem. Didn't say that anywhere.

Comment: @DanielStilman: then let's say that I can't see any benefit of this concept, which is nothing new.

Comment: I am trying to understand if the halting problem shows that a halting-decider as idealized in the problem itself (can decide on all problems UpTo the recursive case described here and the set of all other Turing machines which likewise call our decider and countermand it) could return "Undecideable" for these cases.

Comment: That's ok, it's not about benefit, it's about curiosity. Also, there's no benefit to "breaking" the halting problem, a Turing machine simply can't.